# Abrir Banco de Dados em format .DB

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi

Possuo um Banco de Dados em um arquivo **.DB** de uma aplicação antiga projetada em Delphi.

Meu cliente quer migrar os dados para usar em uma nova aplicação, porém o software antigo do cliente foi projetado em Delphi, o meu problema é, como faço para extrair os dados desse formato?

Comment: Boa tarde.
Para realizar meu TCC desenvolvi um sistema para migração de dados entre banco de dados relacionais (exporta de qualquer banco para qualquer banco, buscando otimização no tempo realizado para uma migração.), se tiver interesse entre em contato que realizo uma demonstração.
Porem para resolver seu problema crie um ODBC, nao sei qual o componente que irá utilizar porem conect-se a este odbc e jogue os dados aonde vc quiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa esse programa [aqui, DB Browser for SQLite.](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser)

Inclusive na imagem de demonstração deles está mostrando um arquivo .db aberto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso não consiga altere o arquivo para .txt e abra no bloco de notas, alguns arquivos não criptografados terão o modelo do banco de dados nos primeiros bytes dele e será visível no bloco de notas.